# Want to remove WP welcome panel

Tags: dashboard

I looked everywhere and I get the same answer

```
remove_action('welcome_panel', 'wp_welcome_panel');
```

which doesn't work with me!

Got last version of 4.9.6 for now

Comment: Adding to `functions.php` of active theme?

Comment: @LiamStewart sure to functions.php

Comment: On what hook are you calling this?

Comment: @TomJNowell sorry, I don't know what hook you're talking about. I just copied that line and paste it in my active theme functions.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old post and you probably found the solution, but maybe I can help someone who ends up here in the future.

This code doesn't work because it has to be inside the function that runs it. Try this:

```
//Function "remove_welcome_panel" with instruction to remove welcome panel
function remove_welcome_panel() {
    remove_action( 'welcome_panel', 'wp_welcome_panel' );
}

//Run above function on admin_init
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_welcome_panel' );
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks